# How to get current window URI last segment

Tags: codeigniter

My current window URL `http://192.168.20.2/vtp/attendance/rawAttendance` and parameter form submit by this URL `"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/attendance/submitParam"` in ajax. With this code below

```
$last = $this->uri->total_segments();
$data['lastSegment'] = $this->uri->segment($last);
```

I got the last URL segment but this not the current window URL segment, this is parameter form URL segment. How do I get my current window URL last segment in my `submitParam controller`when I submit the parameter form.

submit param;

```
$("#submitparam").click(function (e) {  // passing down the event 
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/attendance/submitParam",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: $("#param").serialize() + '&fromAjax=' + true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#result").html(data);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Fail")
                        }
                    });
                    e.preventDefault(); // could also use: return false;
                });
```

controller:

```
public function submitParam() {
        //post from view param
        $round = $this->input->post('round', TRUE);
        $batch = $this->input->post('batchid', TRUE);
        $fromdate = $this->input->post('FromDate', TRUE);
        $todate = $this->input->post('ToDate', TRUE);

        //raw Attendance
        $data['IDS'] = $this->AttendanceModel->raw_attendance_TID($batch);
        $data['Dates'] = $this->AttendanceModel->raw_attendance_Data($batch,$fromdate,$todate);

        //get Batch Attendance
        $data['attendance'] = $this->AttendanceModel->get_attendance($batch,$fromdate,$todate);

        //pass param to preview as attendance title
        $data['batch']=$batch;
        $data['fromDate']=$fromdate;
        $data['toDate']=$todate;

        //get url last segment
        $last = $this->uri->total_segments();
        $lastSegment = $this->uri->segment($last);

        //load view by url last segment
        if ($this->input->post("fromAjax")) {
            $this->load->view('attendance/'.$lastSegment, $data );
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden field in your form with the name url_parameter. set the value of the last paramater which you want in your controller and get that field's value by post/get method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$record_num = end($this->uri->segment_array());
```

Comment: it's also return the same, I mean parameter url last segment, not the browser url last segment.